# What is the best open source SNMP monitoring tool?

Tags: snmp

I am currently working on software that must emit SNMP traps for SNMP versions 1 & 2 and possibly v3 in the future. I have downloaded several and found them to be either too complex or too simplistic. All I want is to view traps and analyze the data structures within them, and the ability to import my custom MIB's. The best I have found so far is ireasonings MIB Browser, but would be greatful for any nice alternatives.

Answer (score 11):

[netsnmp](http://www.net-snmp.org) - should do everything you're after, with a variety of language bindings to suit every taste.

Comment: This is the route I'd take, at least for simple stuff that was mentioned.  It's very easy to setup snmptrapd from Net-SNMP and have it catch incoming traps, then pass them to a Perl script (or external program).  Net-SNMP comes with Perl bindings, and if compiled in, it makes handling the traps very easy.

Answer (score 6):

The only monitoring tools I've used that utilize SNMP monitoring are Nagios, Zenoss, OpenNMS, and the proprietary product from my company - but they're for full network monitoring.

How many devices are you looking to monitor? If it's only a couple, @Andrew's suggestion of netsnmp may be sufficient.